# Ansible ssh error: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe Received exit status from master

Tags: ssh, ansible, shellexecute, broken-pipe

I have a script `/wd/remoteuser/stopALL.sh` on `remotehost` i.e `10.0.0.211` and takes 3 seconds to complete execution and has full permission 775 for remoteuser.

Note: `/wd/remoteuser/stopALL.s`h does not exist on the host where ansible runs.

I wish to trigger the stop script  on `remotehost` from my `ansiblehost`.

Below is how i run my ansible playbook.

```
ansible-playbook /app/playbook/ovs.yml -i /app/playbook/ovs.hosts -t stop -f 5 -e Environment=PROD -e Country=SRILANKA -vvvv
```

cat /app/playbook/ovs.yml

```
---
- name: Play 1- check for login and mount point
  hosts: "*{{ Country }}_{{ Environment }}"
  user: "{{ USER }}"
  any_errors_fatal: true
  vars:
    ansible_ssh_extra_args: -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=90 -o ServerAliveInterval=50
    ansible_ssh_private_key_file: /app/ssh_keys/id_rsa
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

    - name: Execute backup stop1 script
      tags: stop,restart
      script: "{{ stopscript }}"
      args:
        chdir: "{{ stopscript | dirname }}"
      register: stopscriptoutput


    - name: Debug stopscript
      tags: stop,restart
      debug:
        msg: "{{ stopscriptoutput.stdout }}"
```

cat /app/playbook/ovs.hosts

```
[APP_SRILANKA_PROD]
10.0.0.211 USER=remoteuser stopscript=/wd/remoteuser/stopALL.sh countrydet=SRILANKA evt=PROD
```

Output:

```
<10.0.0.211> (0, '', 'OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *\r\ndebug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,gss-gex-sha1-,gss-group14-sha1-]\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4\r\ndebug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 190236\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent\r\ndebug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2\r\ndebug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe\r\ndebug2: Received exit status from master 0\r\n')
fatal: [10.0.0.211]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Could not find or access '/wd/remoteuser/stopALL.sh' on the Ansible Controller.\nIf you are using a module and expect the file to exist on the remote, see the remote_src option"
}

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT *****************************************************************************************************************************************************

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
10.0.0.211                : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I get this ssh read header failed: Broken pipe error even if I use the `shell` module as shown below.

```
- name: Execute backup stop1 script
  tags: stop
  shell: "sleep 90; {{ stopscript }}; sleep 90"
  register: stopscriptoutput
```

Kindly suggest how can I resolve the ssh broken pipe error and get the script to execute remotely?

Comment: few questions :
1. `ansible_ssh_user` permission  issues ? 2. file existence? 3. how does it behave if `sleep 90` is removed from `shell` module.

Comment: @P.... The target file exists with the same user as `remoteuser`and sufficient permissions and privileged. If `sleep 90` is removed we get the same error immediately rather than with a delay.

Comment: The issue was that the script I was trying to execute had `read k` for user input is why it was failing

Comment: @Ashar how did you overcome this issue, please can you explain?. I also have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Set the proxy in environment variable and it started working

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you set it?
just "export http_proxy=http://ip:port" ?